# Collect roofline data for a specific memory level in Intel Advisor

Tags: intel, intel-advisor, roofline

I would like to use Intel Advisor to create a CPU roofline chart for a C++ program. The overhead of data collection phase could be super high if I capture data for all memory levels (adding `--enable-cache-simulation` flag). To that end, I would like to collect data for a specific memory level (only DRAM). So, I was wondering if I can collect data only for a DRAM-level roolfine?

PS: I know that dropping `--enable-cache-simulation` flag will collect data only for L1-level but I'm interested in DRAM not L1.

Comment: I haven't used Intel Advisor, but I'd hope it could use hardware performance counters to measure how code runs on your actual hardware, like counting loads (and maybe stores) that cause L3 cache misses.  e.g. the `mem_load_retired.l3_miss` perf event.  If that doesn't help, maybe someone familiar with Intel Advisor can answer your question.

Comment: @PeterCordes I went through Intel Advisor's manual, but there was no info on using performance counters like `l3_miss`